# Ansible- Delete multiline property from properties file

Tags: properties, ansible, multiline

How to replace multiline property in properties file using ansible

my properties file has a big list of dicts spanned into multiple lines. 
I am able to successfully fetch the value from the properties file without any issues using lookup ini plugin.

Here is my properties file props.txt

```
k1= v1
userlist = [
            { 'user': 'x',
              'city" : 'xc'
            }
            ,{ 'user': 'y',
              'city" : 'yc'
            }
            ,{ 'user': 'z',
              'city" : 'zc'
            }
           ]
k2= v2
```

I am able to get the list of dicts using the following lookup plugin

```
USER_LIST: "{{lookup('ini', 'userlist type=properties file=props.txt')}}"
```

But I need to remove this entry from the properties file.

I tried with `replace:` but unsuccessful. 
can some one suggest how can I acheive this?

Expected props.txt after running the code:

```
k1: v1
k2: v2
```

Comment: Does it has to be done with the lookup of `ini`? Can't it be done with the use of `cat` file, and then some commands?

Comment: @KevinC  All I need is programatically remove a selected multiline variable from a file. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    exclude_vars:
      - userlist

  tasks:

    - name: Create list of variables
      set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|default([]) +
                     [item.split('=').0|trim] }}"
      with_lines: cat props.txt
      when: item is match('^(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*)=(.*)$')

    - name: Exclude variables from the list
      set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|difference(exclude_vars) }}"

    - name: Create list of values
      set_fact:
        my_values: "{{ my_values|default([]) +
                       [lookup('ini', item ~ ' type=properties file=props.txt')] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_vars }}"

    - name: Create dictionary of variables and values
      set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict|default({})| 
                     combine({item.0: item.1}) }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ my_vars }}"
        - "{{ my_values }}"

    - name: Create configuration file
      copy:
        dest: 'props.txt.new'
        content: |
          {% for k,v in my_dict.items() %}
          {{ k }}: {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```
$ cat props.txt.new 
k2: v2
k1: v1
```